# Firebase realtime database not responding: React native : Android

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to app development so I apologise if I've missed any obvious steps. I'm trying to read from a firebase realtime database but there seems to be no return value. The code used is as follows:

```
firebase.app().database("{databaseurl}").ref("/testValue")
        .once('value')
        .then(
            snapshot => {
                console.log(snapshot)
            }
        )
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

The database security rule is set to public so should not be an issue. Also the user is logged in before this part of the code so shouldn't be the issue either.

Android/app/build.gradle/dependencies:

```
    //firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.3.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
```

Steps I've taken so far:

- Updated google-services.json
- Double check android set up steps for react native and firebase
- Rebuild react-native app from scratch

Any help debugging this would be appreciated. I've been on it for 3 days straight now.

Comment: This looks wrong: `firebase.app().database("{databaseurl}")`. It should probably be: `firebase.app().database("${databaseurl}")` or (simpler): `firebase.app().database(databaseurl)`.

Comment: I should have clarified, {databaseurl} is just a placeholder for a string of the url to the db. I just changed so I don't post the raw url on here